# Socket code throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, null

Hi frends im working on my android final year project based on sockets..im using ssynctask to connect socket etc..Everything works fine, since I'm using `AsyncTask` to create a Socket connection ... the socket works fine in the `doInBackground()` method, but when I try to send Sensor data from the`onSensorChanged()` method, I get null pointer exception. I don't know what went wrong. in short Socket returns  NULL outside asyncTask Class...can some 1 help me ?

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.sensorsmart;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{


private static final int SERVERPORT = 8222;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.0.101";
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private   TextView tv ;
public ServerSocket serverSocket=null;
public Socket socket = null;
public BufferedReader in ;
public BufferedWriter out;
public PrintWriter pw ;
public FileWriter writer=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
new MyTask().execute();
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mAccelerometer mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);   
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}
public void onStopClick(View view) {
mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

try {
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8222);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
socket=serverSocket.accept();
Log.i("TcpServer", "CONNECTED");
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
if(!in.ready())
{
Log.i("TcpServer", "READER IS NOT READY");
}

final  String g;
final String c;
String b = null;
Log.i("TcpServer", "GOING");
g=in.readLine();
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),g, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
});

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
String  response = e.getCause().toString();
Log.i("TCP",response);
}
return null;
}

}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
float x = event.values[0];
float y = event.values[1];
float z = event.values[2];
pw.write("g");  //NULL POINT EXCEPTION THROWS HERE
}
}
```

here is log cat :

```
02-06 11:31:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 11:31:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4108): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 11:31:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4108):     at    com.example.sensorsmart.MainActivity.onSensorChanged(MainActivity.java:196)
02-06 11:31:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4108):     at     android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SystemSensorManager.java:204)
02-06 11:31:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4108):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 11:31:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4108):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 11:31:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4759)
02-06 11:31:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 11:31:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 11:31:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
02-06 11:31:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
02-06 11:31:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4108):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Stack trace please. You should really be able to sort out your own NPEs. At least I expect it.

Comment: are you executing this in real device or in emulator ?

Comment: im executing in real device

Comment: can some 1 ans please

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
pw.write("g");  //NULL POINT EXCEPTION THROWS HERE
```

because you are creating different object of `PrintWriter` with same name inside `doInBackground` instead of initializing `pw`. do as:

```
 ....
 Log.i("TcpServer", "CONNECTED");
 in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
 pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);  //initializing `pw` here
 if(!in.ready())
 {
   Log.i("TcpServer", "READER IS NOT READY");
  }
 ....
```

Comment: Dear..! i have edited code..btw  printwriter(),r works 5n in DoInBackground()..but throws exception in OnSensorChanged() method...i mean Socket itself Returns NUll